# How to fix a custom range slider progress not following input range thumb?

Tags: jquery, html, css, input-type-range

I am trying to make a custom range slider with a **progress bar** using jQuery in **HTML/CSS** for Google Chrome browser. I want to make an input type range with a progress bar that follows the input thumb not like my custom input range.

My code is below:

```js
var range2 = $("#newSlider");
var progressBar2 = $(".progressslider");
$(range2).on("input change", function() {
  progressBar2.css("width", $(this).val() + "%");
  rangeValue.text($(this).val() + "%");
});
```

```css
.boxslider {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#newSlider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#newSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(243, 12, 12);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progressslider {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(224, 84, 91);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxslider">
  <input type="range" id="newSlider" min="0" max="100" value="5">
  <div class="progressslider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change **rangeValue** to **$(this)**

```js
var range2 = $("#newSlider");
var progressBar2 = $(".progressslider");
$(range2).on("input change", function() {
  progressBar2.css("width", $(this).val() + "%");
 console.log(this)
  $(this).text($(this).val() + "%");
});
```

```css
.boxslider {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#newSlider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#newSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(243, 12, 12);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progressslider {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(224, 84, 91);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxslider">
  <input type="range" id="newSlider" min="0" max="100" value="5">
  <div class="progressslider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to account for the handle width, i.e. CSS would look something like this:

```
width: calc(15px + ${$(this).val()} * (100% - 30px));
```

where `30px` is the handle width, `15px` is half of that, and `${$(this).val()}` is the current value of the slider between `0` and `1`.

In fact you don't need a separate `div`, but can use gradients to fill different parts of the track.

You can use [input range slider CSS styler](https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler/) to dial that in (and more) to style input range slider across browsers.
I made handle color transparent so you can see how progress is drawn:

```js
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"].slider-progress')) {
  e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value);
  e.style.setProperty('--min', e.min == '' ? '0' : e.min);
  e.style.setProperty('--max', e.max == '' ? '100' : e.max);
  e.addEventListener('input', () => e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value));
}
```

```css
/*generated with Input range slider CSS style generator (version 20211219)
https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler*/
input[type=range].styled-slider {
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*progress support*/
input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress {
  --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
  --ratio: calc((var(--value) - var(--min)) / var(--range));
  --sx: calc(0.5 * 30px + var(--ratio) * (100% - 30px));
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/*webkit*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #F30C0C80;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: calc(1em * 0.5 - 30px * 0.5);
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 1em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #000000;
  box-shadow: none;
}
input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#E0545B,#E0545B) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #000000;
}

/*mozilla*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #F30C0C80;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-track {
  height: 1em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #000000;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#E0545B,#E0545B) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #000000;
}

/*ms*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #F30C0C80;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #000000;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
  margin: -undefined 0 -undefined -undefined;
  background: #E0545B;
  border: none;
  border-right-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="styled-slider slider-progress" style="width:400px;"/>
```